# How to compute @MetaValue's entityTarget from value in Hibernate's @Any?

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I have implemented a solution similar to:
[How to use Hibernate @Any-related annotations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217831/how-to-use-hibernate-any-related-annotations), and it's getting out of hand - I have too many mappings which have similar mapping "scheme":

```
@Any(metaColumn = @Column(name = "something_type"), fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@AnyMetaDef(idType = "long", metaType = "string", metaValues = {
    @MetaValue(value = "A", targetEntity = AImpl.class),
    @MetaValue(value = "B", targetEntity = BImpl.class),
    @MetaValue(value = "C", targetEntity = CImpl.class),
    @MetaValue(value = "D", targetEntity = DImpl.class),
    @MetaValue(value = "E", targetEntity = EImpl.class),
    etc..  })
public BaseSomething getRelatedSometing() {
    return relatedSometing;
}
```

I've tried to keep a value (e.g. "A") that can be computed to a target (e.g. "AImpl").
Is there a way to avoid listing all the implementation by hand, but still keep hibernate happy?

Answer (score 3):

[I asked a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13467367/does-hibernate-support-meta-annotations-for-any), hoping for support for [Spring style meta-annotations](http://blog.springsource.com/2009/05/06/spring-framework-30-m3-released/).

However, In the meantime, the following is working well for me:

```
class SomeClass {
    public static final String SOMETHING_METADEF_NAME = "somethingMetadefName";


    @Any(metaColumn = @Column(name = "something_type"), fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @AnyMetaDef(idType = "long", metaType = "string", name=SomeClass.SOMETHING_METADEF_NAME,
    metaValues = {
            @MetaValue(value = "A", targetEntity = AImpl.class),
            @MetaValue(value = "B", targetEntity = BImpl.class),
            @MetaValue(value = "C", targetEntity = CImpl.class),
            @MetaValue(value = "D", targetEntity = DImpl.class),
            @MetaValue(value = "E", targetEntity = EImpl.class),
            etc..  })
    public BaseSomething getRelatedSometing() {
        return relatedSometing;
    }
}

    // Elsewhere
    @Any(metaColumn = @Column(name = "something_type"), fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
            metaDef=SomeClass.SOMETHING_METADEF_NAME)
    public BaseSomething getAnotherSomething() {
        return relatedSometing;
    }
```

Specifically, I define the relationship once, and give it a `name` property in the `@AnyMetaDef`.  Then, I can reference this from a `@Any(metaDef=MY_NAME)` elsewhere.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks. I wans't aware of reusing a named metadef. It does saves me a bunch of redundant lines. the pain is still specifying the target classes.