# Cannot fetch @Any related entity due to LazyInitializationException

Tags: hibernate, lazy-initialization, any

Could anyone help me how to deal with `@Any` relationship?

I have an interface `InteractionParticipate` which is implemented by everyone who wants to take a part in some kind of messaging interaction. A message is represented by `InteractionMessage` which has a transmitter and a receiver. Since we don't know which entity implementing `InteractionParticipate` will be the receiver (or transmitter) of the message we have to use `@Any` relationship.

I have read [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217831/how-to-use-hibernate-any-related-annotations) which inspired me and wrote in `InteractionMessage` something like that:

```
@Any(metaColumn = @Column(name = "Transmitter_Type"))
@AnyMetaDef(
        idType = "long",
        metaType = "string",
        metaValues = {
                @MetaValue(value = "Applicant", targetEntity = Applicant.class),
                @MetaValue(value = "Vacancy", targetEntity = Vacancy.class)
        })
@JoinColumn(name = "Transmitter_Id")
@LazyToOne(LazyToOneOption.FALSE)
private InteractionParticipate transmitter;

@Any(metaColumn = @Column(name = "Receiver_Type"))
@AnyMetaDef(idType = "long", metaType = "string",
        metaValues = {
                @MetaValue(targetEntity = Applicant.class, value = "Applicant"),
                @MetaValue(targetEntity = Vacancy.class, value = "Vacancy")
        })
@JoinColumn(name = "Receiver_Id")
@LazyToOne(LazyToOneOption.FALSE)
private InteractionParticipate receiver;
```

Database is created well and I can see entities save correctly. But when I try to get an `InteractionMessage` from database

```
InteractionMessage message = (InteractionMessage) session.get(InteractionMessage.class, id);
```

I face I cannot get neither `receiver` nor `transmitter` because **Method threw 'org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException' exception. Cannot evaluate ... Vacancy_$$_javassist_49.toString()**. (Vacancy class is implementing `InteractionParticipate`.)

I tried to play with `@LazyToOne` and even `@LazyCollection` but failed.

Please help me to figure it out. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to access a collection of a detached object.
A detached object means it is not connected to a session. As a result, when accessing a lazy collection, you receive an exception.
This can happen for different reasons. For example, you receive the object by serialization from the front-end.
There are 2 possible solutions, depending what result is desired.

1) You can define the collection to be eagerly fetched. This means that the collection is initialized as soon as the parent object is initialized.
2) You can merge the object (T mergedObject em.merge(detachedObject);) an access its collection.

A small warning: em.merge() returns a merged object. However, the old one is still detached, so remember to access the merged one.