# @ManyToAny annotation in hibernate

Tags: hibernate, annotations

I am unable to understand the use of @ManyToAny annotation in Hibernate. In which case it should be used? I googled it, but the explanations in a couple of websites just bounced over my head...

Can anyone explain it with a simple example? How's it different from @ManyToMany and @ManyToOne?

Comment: seems like a similar question to [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/217831/how-to-use-hibernate-any-related-annotations).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[The javadoc](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/ManyToAny.html) says:

> Defines a ToMany association pointing to different entity types. Matching the according entity type is done through a metadata discriminator column. This kind of mapping should be only marginal.

So instead of having a ManyToMany between Student and Course, you could have a ManyToAny between Student and [Course or Teacher], and the metadata discriminator column would say, for a given row, if it points to a Course or to a Teacher.